# Angular post request works in postman but do not work in angular

Tags: angular, postman, angular-httpclient

This is my POST request in postman to upload a file into drive. It works perfectly
[image]

But, In my angular project it does not work. I get error 201 Invalid Credentials. I checked the access-token it is correct. and with the same access-token it works in postman
[image]

Here is the error i get 
[image]

What is the issue here? and How should I correct it?

Comment: you make sure that in develepor tools u got the header there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I used **FETCH** instead of **HttpClient**. But i couldn't find a proper reason for its behaviour.